# pyspark zip file creation using gradle

Tags: gradle, pyspark, pygradle

How can we build pyspark project using gradle? I want to build it just like how we buuild a scala gradle project. The build must do compilation and zip file creation of pyspark project . Must be able to do the  python unit testing if possible..